# Python Frequency table

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, frequency

I want to make frequency table by below table.

number       1         2         4         6       Sum

frequency   0.4      0.25    0.15    0.2    1

And I wrote the below code.

```
import random
from collections import Counter

number = [1, 2, 4, 6]
probability = [0.4, 0.25, 0.15, 0.2]


def Cdf(p):
  y_cdf = []
  s = 0
  n = len(p)
  for i in range(0, n):
    s = s + p[i]
    y_cdf.append(s)
  return y_cdf


def rand_G(p):
  q = random.uniform(0, 1)
  n = len(p)
  c = Cdf(p)
  for i in range(0, n):
    if q <= c[i]:
      return i

def rand2_G(p, n):
  a = []
  for i in range(n):
    a.append(rand_G(p))
  return a

def Table(a):
  c = Counter(a)
  pair = c.most_common()
  pair.sort()
  print('Number\tFrequency')
  for x in pair:
    print('{0}\t{1}'.format(x[0], x[1]))

data = rand2_G(probability, 10000)
Table(data)
```

But result is 
Number  Frequency
0   3990
1   2495
2   1521
3   1994

Above Table, Number is not 1,2,4,6.

How can I make frequency table with number 1,2,4,6(above number list)?

Comment: What is the relationship of `Cdf`, `rand_G`, `rand2_G` to your question?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with python 3.6, there is [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences):

> `random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)`
>   Return a k sized list of elements chosen from the population with
>   replacement. If the population is empty, raises IndexError.
>
> If a weights sequence is specified, selections are made according to
>   the relative weights. Alternatively, if a cum_weights sequence is
>   given, the selections are made according to the cumulative weights
>   (perhaps computed using itertools.accumulate()). For example, the
>   relative weights [10, 5, 30, 5] are equivalent to the cumulative
>   weights [10, 15, 45, 50]. Internally, the relative weights are
>   converted to cumulative weights before making selections, so supplying
>   the cumulative weights saves work.
>
> If neither weights nor cum_weights are specified, selections are made
>   with equal probability. If a weights sequence is supplied, it must be
>   the same length as the population sequence. It is a TypeError to
>   specify both weights and cum_weights.
>
> The weights or cum_weights can use any numeric type that interoperates
>   with the float values returned by random() (that includes integers,
>   floats, and fractions but excludes decimals).